# Genymotion Emulators are not shown in Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, genymotion

I would like to use Genymotion from Titanium Studio in Windows PC. But with `ti info -t android` command, `Genymotion Emulators None` is shown in console of Titanium Studio. Do I have to do additional settings? I didn't have any trouble in Mac PC.

I followed processes in this website:

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/12/using-genymotion-with-titanium-3-2/

Also I installed Genymotion and some Genymotion emulators.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Set The path in the titanium studio.

Windows-studio-preference-platform Android

Genymotion Path:
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\genymotion.exe

Genymotion Player:
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\player.exe

Genymotion VBoxManage:
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VboxManage.exe

Comment: The Titanium box is a little wonky.  In 3.4.1, when I browsed for the file locations, it seemed to somehow change the current working folder in the background.  While the box displayed the path correctly initially, it still did not work.  I went back into the dialog, and it only showed the exe name, with no path.  The solution for me was to enter the entire path without browsing for the files.  Also, your paths may/will vary from above, particularly if you did not install into the default locations, or perhaps used the version of GenyMotion with the VirtualBox included.